# Java Linux Arm Remote Debugging With Eclipse: "Profiling and debugging agents are not supported in this VM"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, embedded-linux

I am part of a team working on a library for the First Robotics Competition. We have a series of tools that allow teams to write and debug their robots using eclipse along with our own custom eclipse plugins. Before now, we were confined to using a custom version of JDK 1.3 to run programs on the CRIO which had a built in debug mode. However we are now using jdk-linux-arm (a version of Java 8 for embedded ARM chips). In order to debug our programs they have to be run remotely on the chip because of JNI dependencies.

The command that I am using to run the program in debug mode is:

```
killall java
killall FRCUserProgram
sleep 1
nohup /usr/local/frc/JRE/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y -jar FRCUserProgram.jar
```

However when I try this I get the following Output:

```
[sshexec] killall: java: no process killed
[sshexec] Profiling and debugging agents are not supported in this VM
[sshexec] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
[sshexec] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Are there any other methods to enable remote debugging for JDK Linux Arm through eclipse? This has to be able to run through eclipse with breakpoints enabled an all of the other features that eclipse debugging offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the jvm to support debugging using jrecreate

jrecreate --dest tmp/JRE_DEBUG/ --profile compact2 --vm client --kee
p-debug-info --debug

see this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-platforms/jrecreate.htm#CACGABAD

use the following command line to run the program:

java -XX:+UsePerfData -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8348,server=y,suspend=y -jar FRCUserProgram.jar